# Capture response time between multiple servers

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, response-time

We have an application which has few layers similar to below diagram.

[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctLpl.png)

And it's required to do a performance test to measure the end to end application performance.

I can simulate the load using a tool like JMeter, and it will give the total response time. but I need to capture the time taken between each node:

- Client Application -> API
- API -> ERP -> API
- API ->Client Application

Is there a way to capture this information?

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your JMeter is simulating "Client Application" interaction with API, you will only have overall performance. But you could split your perf test into 2 parts:

1. Test API -> ERP -> API in isolation, by producing the same requests as your API would against ERP directly.
2. Test Client Application -> API -> ERP -> API -> Client Application. You can then subtract results of test 1, and that will give you an approximation of Client Application -> API -> Client Application.

Of course this is much more complicated than doing one test. A more economical approach is

1. Either rely on application logging (best way, if available). Usually it should be, since both API and ERP are likely some web applications deployed on Web/App server, and most of them are capable of logging enough data. So it will be more exercise in result parsing.
2. Or have other "man in the middle" which will record when request arrived and left each server. It could be a load balancer, or an application that records HTTP traffic.

Comment: Thanks Kiril, for the suggestions. I will look in to that. Is there any tool that we can  deploy an agent app in each server and capture this information directly from the main tool?